# Словосочетание. Необходимо понять ответ на вопрос

Tags: словосочетания

Есть упражнение, в котором написаны следующие фразы: сшили из шелковой ткани, остановились около высокого здания, плыли по голубому небу, подъехали к лесной сторожке, смотрели интересный спектакль, вылетел в открытое окно...

Подскажите пожалуйста, является ли каждая из этих фраз словосочетанием? Мне объясняют так: это словосочетание, потому что идут в упражнении через запятую, а не точку. На каком основании они делают такой вывод? Тут же целые фразы, имеющие несколько словосочетаний внутри себя, или я ошибаюсь? Разве можно говорить, что каждая из этих фраз - отдельное словосочетание?

Answer (score 3):

Понять структуру словосочетания поможет "Лингвистический энциклопедический словарь":

> Со структурной точки зрения различаются словосочетания **простые,
> сложные и комбинированные.** **Простые словосочетания могут быть
> двучленными, трёхчленными и четырёхчленными.** Двучленные словосочетания
> образуются на основе **одиночной связи** («читать книгу», «новый дом»).
> Трёхчленные и четырёхчленные словосочетания образуются **на основе
> двойной и тройной сильной связи** («отдать книгу ученику», «перевести
> книгу с русского на английский»). Трёхчленные словосочетания могут
> быть также образованы на основе соединения сильной связи и такой
> слабой связи, которая невозможна без сильной («открыть дверь гостю»).
>
> **Сложные словосочетания создаются разными типами связи стержневого
> слова,** например согласованием и примыканием («новый жилец наверху»),
> управлением и примыканием («быстро выполнить работу»).
>
> **Комбинированные
> словосочетания образуются на основе связей, исходящих от разных
> стержневых слов**, и представляют собой, таким образом, соединение
> словосочетаний. Так, комбинированное словосочетание «увлечённо читать
> интересную книгу» образовано соединением трёх простых словосочетаний:
> «читать увлечённо», «читать книгу», «интересная книга».

https://les.academic.ru/1060/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5

*Сшили из шелковой ткани, остановились около высокого здания, плыли по голубому небу, подъехали к лесной сторожке, смотрели интересный спектакль, вылетел в открытое окно* - это словосочетания, потому что данные сочетания слов объединены разными видами **синтаксической** и семантической связи. Сшили (из чего?) из ткани - управление,  из какой ткани? Из шёлковой. - согласование. **В словосочетании две связи - это сложное словосочетание.**

Сложные словосочетания представляют собою **распространение слова целым словосочетанием**: сшили (из чего?) из шёлковой ткани.
В сложном словосочетании можно выделить две пары: *сшили из ткани* и *из шёлковой ткани*, но их связывает более расчлененное представление, выражаемое всем словосочетанием.

Так что в Вашем упражнении даны сложные словосочетания, из которых Вы, видимо, должны вычленить простые.

Answer (score 1):

ФРАЗА, [от греч. phrasis — выражение, оборот речи].

Вопрос звучал так: *Разве можно говорить, что каждая из этих фраз — отдельное словосочетание?*

**В данной записи (через запятую),** очевидно, можно. Перед нами — **сложные словосочетания.**

Но вот вопрос: **сколько простых словосочетаний содержится в сложном**? Я полагаю, что не более одного. Сложное словосочетание (с подчинительной связью) состоит их отдельных компонентов, но при этом является  **единым целым** и имеет одно **основное стержневое слово**. А вот разложить сложное словосочетание на отдельные простые словосочетания можно (как, к примеру, мы слово раскладываем на морфемы).

**Комбинированные словосочетания**? Как мне кажется, термин этот несущественный (в новых учебниках его нет). Вероятно, это  просто углубление в детали, которые только мешают видеть общую картину.

Приведенные словосочетания **глагольного типа**, то есть стержневым словом является глагол. Примечательно, что такие словосочетания могут быть  односоставными **предложениями**. Например: *Лошади вдруг остановились, и я выглянул из повозки. Стало понятно: подъехали к лесной сторожке.*

Но это еще одна тема для размышления: чем словосочетание **отличается** от предложения?

Соответственно, вопрос о запятых в приведенной записи не такой уж праздный.

Answer (score 0):

Отвечать-то надо на вопрос, а не рассуждать о всяком-разном.

А вопрос сформулирован так, что надо объяснить логику какого-то консультанта. В принципе-то она понятна. Если какой-то фрагмент текста не оформлен в виде законченного предложения, то его лучше считать словосочетанием. Но, простите, это настолько все примитивно и бесполезно, что ниже всякой критики.

Comment: Это для ребенка 4-го класса. Который выполнил упражнение в рамках своих знаний, полученных за последний год, в которых нет расширенных понятий и определений, все узко.  Словосочетание- два слова: зависимое и главное, а ему говорят, что нет, эти фразы и есть словосочетания, он этого не понимает...

Comment: Интересно, по каким программам занимается эта школа, в 4 классе не может быть речи о сложном словосочетании. Задание-то какое было? Отличить предложение от словосочетания? Тогда возможно, потому что дети знают признаки предложения - законченность высказывания.

Comment: Задание, наверное, было такое: _Подберите к каждому имени существительному подходящее по смыслу имя прилагательное из слов для справок. Запишите словосочетания.  Укажите падеж имён существительных и имён прилагательных, выделите окончания._ См. http://1-4klass.ru/index.php/russkij-yazyk/47-gdz-reshebniki-po-russkomu-yazyku/gdz-reshebnik-po-russkomu-yazyku-4-klass-2-chast-avtor-v-p-kanakina-v-g-goretskij/315-gdz-russkij-yazyk-4-klass-kanakina-uprazhnenie-18.html